# MySQL Join at a loss

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Please help anyone!

I would like, **for example**, user_id 27 to return case_id 1 and 2 because another user_id with the same company has created the cases.

User ID 27 is an example as the table is quite large and so I would need a generalised SQL statement somehow.

A CodeIgniter Active Query would be very helpful but may be too complex?

```
Cases
case_id | case_user | case_name
1, 25, Test Case A
2, 25, Test Case B
3, 26, Test Case C

Users
user_id | user_email | user_company
25, example-email-a, Company Alpha
26, example-email-b, Company Beta
27, example-email-c, Company Alpha
```

Many thanks

Comment: What's your relations between the tables? In this case you can use the != operator, but it won't help for a bigger tables. You should have for example user_company related in both tables, so you can make proper joins everytime you call the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Cases 
WHERE case_user IN 
(SELECT user_id FROM Users WHERE user_company=(
   SELECT user_company FROM Users WHERE user_id=27) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, I also need to return the originators email_address so user_id 27 for case_id 1 and 2 I need user_email = example-email-a. Ah so complicated. Thanks again

Comment: SELECT * FROM cases JOIN users ON users.user_id = cases.case_user WHERE case_user IN (SELECT user_id FROM Users WHERE user_company=(SELECT user_company FROM Users WHERE user_id=27))

Answer (score 0):

try this. it is not return case_id 1 and 2 for  user_id 27 but
for user_id 25 it return case_id 1 and 2

```
SELECT * FROM `Users`
LEFT JOIN `Cases` ON `Users`.`user_id`=`Cases`.`case_user` 
WHERE `Users`.`user_id`=25
```

Comment: Do you think it will return for user_id = 27, a case_id = 1 and on the next row case_id = 2, I think it will show NULLs

Answer (score 0):

This is for teh data u showed as example output.

```
 SELECT S1.USER_ID, C.CASE_ID
 FROM USERS S1
 JOIN USERS S2
 ON S1.USER_ID <> S2.USER_ID
 AND S1.USER_COMPANY = S2.USER_COMPANY
 JOIN CASES C
 ON S2.USER_ID = C.CASE_USER
```